# When to use onclick in HTML?

Tags: html, onclick, href

HI,

For a tag, you can execute javascript through href or onclick.

When should I use onclick instead of href?

for me, only advantage I get with onclick is that you can hide javascript function name and parameters from your visitors.

Comment: i am guessing anything you wish to have onclick attached at the sametime that it isn't a `<a>` tag.  anybody can find out about your javascript if they put effort into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you won't use either. Ideally your link is a normal hyperlink with an `href` value referencing a fragment (`#foo`) or URL. Ideally the link would just work as-is without Javascript, too.

You'd then use [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) that attaches itself to links or other DOM elements as needed and only if Javascript is available:

```
<a href="/some/action" id="foobar">Do some action!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // do something
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Dang, 14 seconds faster than me, and with code examples, too! +1

Comment: @Matt Ball // I appreciate your answer as well!!

Answer (score 5):

### Don't use either.

Write [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need onclick when more things should be done than jumping to another page.