# html onClick condition Link

Tags: html, forms, onclick, href, html-select

SO basically im trying to create a button on a html webpage that uses or checks the values from two drop down lists and relative to that it will link to the appropriate page.
But the IF statements dont seem to work...

i tried using regular href Links but this didnt end well, such as [When to use onclick in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138215/when-to-use-onclick-in-html)

here is my code:

```
<select name="Module">
<option value="Module 10">Module 10</option>
<option value="Module 11">Module 11</option>
<option value="Module 20">Module 20</option>
<option value="Module 60">Module 60</option>
<option value="Module 70">Module 70</option>
<option value="Module 85">Module 85</option>
</select>


<select name="Sector">
<option value="Sector1">Sector1</option>
<option value="Sector2">Sector2</option>
<option value="Sector3">Sector3</option>
<option value="Sector4">Sector4</option>
</select>


<FORM> 
<INPUT type="button" value="OK" 
onClick="if (( Module=='Module 10') && (Sector=='Sector1)) {location.href='M10_S1.html'}"> 
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
<form>
<select name="Module">
<option value="1">Module 1</option>
<option value="2">Module 2</option>
<option value="3">Module 3</option>
<option value="4">Module 4</option>
<option value="5">Module 5</option>
<option value="6">Module 6</option>
</select>


<select name="Sector">
<option value="1">Sector1</option>
<option value="2">Sector2</option>
<option value="3">Sector3</option>
<option value="4">Sector4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Confirm" onClick="location.href='./M' + Module.value + '_S' + Sector.value + '.htm'"> 
</form>
```

The file names will be formatted as "M#_S#.htm"

Comment: so if i used this and selected Module 10 and Deck 1
it would link me to;  ./mModule 10_dDeck 1.htm?
or is ./m a special character?

Comment: It is taking the value from the `value`, not the `innerText` of the `option`. So for the example you used: it would take the "10" and the "1" It puts them into the link with the "M" and "_d" already defined. The reason for defining it in the link instead of the option is purely efficiency.

Comment: yeah re-read it and noticed the vlaue changes. That is very efficient, thanks!