# How do I disable a link with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do you know how to disable link for user only? I have

```
<div class="searchoffertext" onclick="searchoffertext_selected('Banana')"><a href="./search/Banana">Banana</a></div>
```

So idea is that link /search/Banana is a valid link and I want to keep it for search indexing engines. However, I want when user click on link, the function searchoffertext_selected was called and nothing more happened.

Comment: You want user to see the redirected page or not?  if not, why you need to keep it in an anchor tag. Use buttons instead?

Comment: Just for search engines. I do not know how they work with ajax data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To stop the link from taking its default action add `return false;` to the `onclick` event:

```
<div class="searchoffertext" onclick="searchoffertext_selected('Banana'); return false;"><a href="./search/Banana">Banana</a></div>
```

It's probably a better idea to put the `onclick` directly on the `<a>`

But an even better approach would be to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to attach an event to the link via a selector.

See also: [Stackoverflow: When to use onclick in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138215/when-to-use-onclick-in-html)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#selector').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

VanilaJS:

```
<a onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: There's no need to load jQuery to do something this basic.

Comment: But... [not enough jQuery](http://motyar.blogspot.ca/2013/01/1-not-enough-jquery.html)

Comment: I appreciate that, but I did give a Vanilla JS solution.

Comment: True, but [`return false` !== `preventDefault()`](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

## js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.searchoffertext > a').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  searchoffertext_selected(this.getAttribute("data-fruit"));
}
```

## html

```
<div class="searchoffertext">
    <a href="./search/Banana" data-fruit="Banana">Banana</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no default action executed on a `click` event of a `div`.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 You understand that events bubble, right? And I'm not sure if the answer was edited, but the selector is `.searchoffertext > a`, so there are no `div` events here

Comment: The answer has been edited, there was no `> a` in there before.

Comment: @Ian Yes I originally left out the > a but about the same time as rink's comment added it in

Comment: There is a `[0]` missing after the selector, i.e. `...querySelectorAll('.searchoffertext > a')[0].onclick`... because, unlike with the almighty jQuery, stuff doesn't automatically apply to the entire list of elements.

Comment: @frnhr you are right. I suppose you could surround with a for loop and use the index to have the effect intended

Answer (score -2):

### HTML

```
<div class="searchoffertext" onclick="searchoffertext_selected('Banana')">
    <a href="./search/Banana">Banana</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

Use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), but this is [unsupported in versions of IE older than 11](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

```
.searchoffertext > a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

[Prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) from executing when the link is clicked:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.searchoffertext > a'), i;
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```